# Django runserver - can't serve video files

Tags: django, video

When running Django in local mode using the runserver command video files are not loaded in the browser properly. I get the error

> An error occurred trying to load the resource.

All other static files serve fine such as images, javascript and css.

Comment: Also note if I serve the videos from nginx or apache they load fine in the browser.

Comment: Update - video files are served properly to internet explorer browser and Firefox, just not safari or chrome

Comment: Does this mean, that video works on chrome and safari in production?

Comment: Yes that is correct, the problem only appears when running the run server command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the answer finally, Django's runserver does not support byte range requests. See this thread:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-developers/NZ1qTkZ6vok/fhdz7rTtL1EJ

And this ticket:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22479

Comment: Any solution? Should i download firefox on iphone?

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Of course you must have STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS set properly in your settings file.

Comment: yes static files are configured correctly, this appears to be a problem specifically with video files.

Comment: @turbotux Could you provide template code responsible for displaying video on the page?

Comment: <video src="{{ item.media_item.video.url }}" controls>
                                        Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
                                    </video>