# issue with running Django server

Tags: django

When I run Django in local mode using the runserver command video files can not be loaded in the browser. All other static files, such as images, javascript and css, serve fine.

Comment: Can you please add your error stacktrace in the question?

Comment: Are the videos uploaded or put as static files (resources)?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate to [Django runserver - can't serve video files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169831/django-runserver-cant-serve-video-files/42376112#42376112)

The answer it that  Django's runserver does not support byte range requests. See this thread:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-developers/NZ1qTkZ6vok/fhdz7rTtL1EJ

And this ticket:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22479